# "Finance" is to "financial" as "trade" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

What goes in the blank?

> Commerce → Commercial
>       Finance  → Financial
>       Trade    → __________

Comment: The -ial suffix is typically attached to English nouns of Latinate/Romance origin, turning them into adjectives; whereas *trade* is of Germanic origin.

Comment: @TRomano: Are you sure? Trade is also French, tradere is Latin (for handing over something...), and the German equivalent is Handel.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One word is **mercantile**:

> Related to trade
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mercantile)

Answer (score 31):

[Trade](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trade) is also an adjective;  ( from TFD)

> - of or relating to trade or commerce.
> - (Commerce) intended for or available only to people in industry or business: trade prices.

Answer (score 12):

Trade    -> Trading

> trading company, trading post, insider trading, trading partner, trading port, trading account

Answer (score 3):

The adjective of trade can be also trade, e.g., trade secret, trade agreement, trade protocol, etc. If "commercial" is used in the same adjectival sense, it is ok.

Answer (score -2):

Transactional

Hope this helps :)

Comment: One word answers tend to get deleted on EL&U. If you could explain why you consider *transactional* to be a valid answer, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score -7):

finance is to financial and trade is to enterprise.